# Cannot login with control+alt+delete after remapping the control keys. Is there a way to undo this or another way to login?

Tags: windows-10, login, ctrl-alt-delete

Normally, when I turn on my Windows 10 PC), I have to press on <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> to be able to enter my password and login to the desktop. Now I can't do that because both of my <kbd>control</kbd> keys are remapped (I did this to test a program).

I tried going to safe mode through the command prompt but get the message:

> “The boot configuration data store could not be opened. The requested system device cannot be found.”

I am using a work laptop. I tried to contact them but it will take them time to fix it.

It was a stupid move I know. But is there any way I can resolve this on my own?

Comment: From where? I never use ctrl+alf+del to log in .. Maybe stupid question, but if I log off I hit keyboard and it displays pwd field, when I power up same thing.

Comment: I edited the question I hope it's more clear. When I turn my work pc, I need to press on ctrl alt del to be able to enter my password and unlock the computer.

Comment: I concur with @JoepvanSteen, when booting my PC I don't have to press CTRL-ALT-DEL to log in... How did you remap the keyboard? It's an important information that is missing. Did you define a new keyboard layout? If yes, pressing WIN-SPACE will toggle the keyboard layout (hoping you have not remaped these ones...)

Comment: I remapped with an app called sharpKeys. I only remapped the ctrl keys. It's probably because it's a work laptop that's why I have to press these keys. I also have Bitlocker installed.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen It's a [group policy entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/interactive-logon-do-not-require-ctrl-alt-del) you may setup for establishing a trusted login channel. In fact it's quite common on work machines.

Comment: @PasWei, thank you!

Comment: It's a work PC and you remapped keys -- looks like IT should help, lest something make he problem worse. While it might be a bit embarrassing to ask them, likely IT has an image to restore the PC.

Comment: Regarding OP's problem I'd try using an external keyboard, maybe you're lucky and the mapping only applies to the internal keyboard. But that's just a hunch..

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I actually called the IT and they told they don' t have a solution yet. They will call me back in few days. But I posted this question because I need my laptop back asap.

Comment: @PasWei unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: I think an external keyboard might work here - or ... could you RDP into the laptop, which would bypass the need for the three fingered salute and change it back from a remote session?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I tried external keyboard it didn't work. And to RDP I first need the laptop to be unlocked, which I can't do

Comment: holding down the power button should force shut it off, then you could restart, which might remove the lock

Comment: I think the only solution would be to reinstall windows or restore a copy. I don't think there is any easier solution.

Comment: Your IT staff may be able to remotely access your registry and change the key maps. That is where Sharpkeys writes them and Windows reads them. In the future, you can also map JUST your left or right Ctrl key, leaving the other available for login duties. But as others have noted, this question needs to go to your IT staff, not here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by opening the on screen keyboard using `windows` key and `U`.